# Laravel 5 relation issue

Tags: php, laravel

In my orders table i get `user_id` and `address_id` relation for both columns are the same, I can get info out of `users` table but not from `addresses` table!

`Order` model:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }

  public function address(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Address::class, 'address_id');
  }
```

`Address` model:

```
public function user(){
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }

    public function order(){
         return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
      }
```

`user` model (just for compare)

```
public function orders(){
       return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }

public function addresses(){
       return $this->hasMany(Address::class);
    }
```

**Now** I can get user info such as

```
{{$order->user->name}}
```

but cannot get my address info such as:

```
{{$order->address->address}}
```

Error i get:

> Trying to get property of non-object

any idea?

## UPDATE

```
Order {#878 ▼
  #fillable: array:11 [▶]
  #casts: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:17 [▼
    "id" => 17
    "ordernu" => "4491084283"
    "user_id" => 1
    "orderstatus_id" => 7
    "address_id" => 2
    "payment_id" => null
    "product_name" => ""[{\"id\":29,\"name\":\"effewf\",\"price\":24524,\"quantity\":1,\"attributes\":[{\"attr\":{\"label\":\"Gray\",\"price\":\"7000.00\"}},{\"attr\":{\"label\":\"Red ▶"
    "product" => null
    "quantity" => null
    "price" => null
    "note" => "xxxxxxx"
    "address" => null
    "phone" => "xxxxxx"
    "buyer_name" => "xxxxxxxxxx"
    "buyer_email" => "admin@admin.com"
    "created_at" => "2018-01-22 14:39:58"
    "updated_at" => "2018-01-22 14:39:58"
```

`addresses` table

[image: screen1]

Comment: Please show results for `{{ dd($order) }}`

Comment: $order->address->address? or is it $order->address->user

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin updated

Comment: @RohanShewale second address in name of my column in addresses table such as name in users table

Comment: try printing `{{$order->address}}` or `dd($order->address)`

Comment: @Sohel0415 `null`

Comment: do you have any address with id 2??

Comment: Try changing both `belongsTo` to `hasOne` in your order model.

Comment: @Sohel0415 yes i do

Comment: Do the same in Address model too

Comment: @SapneshNaik same result is still `null` on dd. + my user might have more than 1 order with same address is not good if i define it as hasOne.

Comment: Is `address` a column on your `addresses` table?

Comment: @btl yes it is.

Comment: The relation should be `hasMany` between `Address` and `Order` in your `Address` model.

Comment: @btl `Trying to get property of non-object `    `public function order(){
     return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `address` property in the `Order` model, that's why you're always getting `null`. This returns property and not related address:

```
$order->address
```

So, rename the relationship to make it work:

```
public function orderAddress()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Address::class, 'address_id');
}
```

And use it:

```
{{ $order->orderAddress->address }}
```